# Issue in MATLAB installation

Tags: matlab

I have finished the installation of MATLAB 2012a till 100%. After completing to 100% it shows this screen. After this I have no any shortcut of MATLAB on my desktop (I don't know why). I didn't understand what it want to say. I think I have to download all this. I just want to ask that I have to download all this individually or if there is some installer like thing which download and install all this.
My OS is Windows 7.

[image: The screen after completing the setup]

Comment: You haven't finished 100% of the installation at the step in your screen shot. You still have to press `Next` and you will probably be invited to `Activate` your products. Once all the steps are done, the last installation page should propose you to run Matlab (and you'll probably have a shortcut at this point, unless you unticked the option)

Comment: After this Next I have last screen with Finish button.

Comment: Matlab is installed, the issue is that if you want to compile code, you need a supported compiler, which they link you to a list in the top line. If you don't need to compile code, you should be good to go.

Comment: @Trogdor Ok thanks. And yes I want to compile code and I just want to ask that I have to download all this individually or if there is some installer like thing which download and install all this.

Comment: The programs listed are already installed, so don't worry about that. You just need to install a supported compiler see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2012a/win64.html) for a list